# Find any date value which format is dd-mmm-yy in a column and change that cell color

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Hello()

Dim lRow As Integer
Dim MR As Variant
Dim Cell As Variant
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("A2:A" & lRow)

        For Each Cell In MR
        If Cell.Value = Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yy") Then Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        Next


End Sub
```

I am Trying to find any date value with this format "10-Jan-16" in whole column A but this code is not working,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColourCells()

    Dim lRow As Integer

    Do While Range("A" & lRow + 1).Value <> ""

        lRow = lRow + 1

        If Range("A" & lRow).Text = Format(Range("A" & lRow).Text, "dd-MMM-yy") Then

            Range("A" & lRow).Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 10

        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

Checking the "Text" property will give you what you are seeing in Excel, which is not the same as what's held in the "Value" property.